# How can I call LLVM IR arg with only one arg?

Tags: llvm, variadic-functions, llvm-ir

In LLVM IR, if I define printf as a single arg func, I'm able to use it. However, if I define it as vararg, it gives an error:

```
@msg = constant [13 x i8] c"hello world\0A\00"

declare i32 @printf(i8*) ; works
;declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)   ; error: '@printf' defined with type 'i32 (i8*, ...)*'
                                ;   call i32 @printf(i8* %msg)

define i32 @main () {
    %msg = getelementptr [13 x i8]* @msg, i64 0, i64 0
    call i32 @printf(i8* %msg)
    ret i32 0
}
```

How do I tell LLVM IR that `printf` is vararg, but call it with only one argument?

Answer (score 1):

Note this passage from the [description of the `call` instruction in the LLVM Language Reference](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#call-instruction) (emphasis mine):

> 7. 'fnty': shall be the signature of the function being called. The argument types must match the types implied by this signature. This type can be omitted *if the function is not varargs*.

So if the function *is* variadic, you do need to provide the function type as part of the call instruction.

Comment: Could you please explain the `fnty` when calling `declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)`? I see that I need `call i32 (i8*,...)*`.  What is the final `*` for?

Comment: @SRobertJames Basically all functions have pointer types because function names represent the address where the function starts (similar to global variables except that you're not going to load or store functions).